# Conditional cumulative sum from two columns

Tags: r, dataframe, purrr, cumsum, accumulate

I can't get my head around the following problem.

Assuming the follwoing data:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(source = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C"),
             value  = c(5, 10, NA, NA, NA, 20),
             add    = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4))
```

What I want to do is: for all cases where `source == "B"`, I want to calculate the cumulative sum of the previous row's `value` and the current row's `add`. Of course, for the first "B" row, I need to provide a starting value for `value`. Note: in this case, it would be fine if we just take the value from the last "A" row.

So for row 3, the result would be 10 + 1 = 11.
For row 4, the result would be 11 + 2 = 13.
For row 5, the results would be 13 + 3 = 16.

I tried to use `purrr::accumulate`, but I failed in many different ways, e.g. I thought I can do:

```
df %>%
  mutate(test = accumulate(add, .init = 10, ~.x + .y))
```

But this leads to error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `test`.
i `test = accumulate(add, .init = 10, ~.x + .y)`.
i `test` must be size 6 or 1, not 7.
```

Same if I use `.init = value`

And I also didn't manage to do the job only on group B (although this is probably no issue, I think I can probably performa on the full data frame and then just replace values for all non-B rows).

Expected output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  source value   add  test
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A          5     1    NA
2 A         10     1    NA
3 B         NA     1    11
4 B         NA     2    13
5 B         NA     3    16
6 C         20     4    NA
```

Comment: Are there multiple runs of Bs?

Comment: No, just the three consecutive ones like in the example.

Comment: Then even `df %>%
    mutate(test = lag(value)) %>%
    group_by(source) %>%
    mutate(test = first(test) + cumsum(add))` would work.

Comment: oh my, this looks much easier. Happy to upvote if you provide an answer. Note that in the lag function, you'd need to add a default value for the first row, otherwise the result will be NA everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were essentially in the right direction. Since you provide an `.init` value to `accumulate`, the resulting vector is of size `n+1`, with the first value being `.init`. You have to remove the first value to get a vector that fit to your column size.

Then, if you want NAs on the remaining values, here's a way to do it. Also, since the "starting row" is the third, `.init` has to be set to 8.

```r
df %>%
  mutate(test = 
           ifelse(source == "B", accumulate(add, .init = 8, ~.x + .y)[-1], NA))

# A tibble: 6 x 4
  source value   add  test
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A          5     1    NA
2 A         10     1    NA
3 B         NA     1    11
4 B         NA     2    13
5 B         NA     3    16
6 C         20     4    NA
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks. Need to contemplate a bit about the manual setting of the init value in my rel-life example, but that's gonna work. I'll probably first group by source, then set the first value per group to my desired value and then run `.init = first(value)`,

Answer (score 0):

[@tmfmnk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5964557/tmfmnk) provided an awesome answer and they deserve full credit (NOT ME)

Below is the same code from their comment (for more visibility, while also setting an initial value)

> ```
> init_value = 10
> df = df %>%     
>   mutate(test = lag(value)) %>%  
>   group_by(source) %>%    
>   mutate(test = init_value + cumsum(add))
> ```

Comment: When using a manual init_value, you don't even need the first mutate.

Comment: is init_value known and is there only one init_value? this is not flexible